# Русские буквы при сохранении в бд из буфера

Tags: vb.net

Пытаюсь записать файл перетаскивая его из outlook в программу, все работает файл в БД записывается но проблема если файл содержит русские буквы то записывается некорректно.

Поискал в интернете пишут что проблема с кодировкой, но как перекодировать файл не разобрался

```
Dim theStream As Stream = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor")

theStream.Read(fileGroupDescriptor, 0, 512)
If fileGroupDescriptor(0) = 1 Then
    ''Если в пачке только один файл, то его можно дернуть прямо из буфера

    Dim fileName As New StringBuilder("")
    Dim i As Integer = 76
    While Not fileGroupDescriptor(i) = 0                   

        fileName.Append(Convert.ToChar(fileGroupDescriptor(i)))
        i = i + 1
        If i = 512 Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
    theStream.Close()                
    Dim tFilename As String = fileName.ToString()
```

Comment: `то записывается некорректно` - как именно записывается?

Comment: типа такого Aiaa?aiiinou.pdf

Comment: Это же VB.NET, а не VB 6?

Comment: Это же VB.NET, а не VB 6? – Alexander Petrov
да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел пример на С# и переделал для себя [пример кириллицы](http://debugru.com/c/izvlech-vlozhenie-outlook-i-zapisat-v-bd)

```
Dim tFilename = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(fileGroupDescriptor.Skip(76).ToArray())
```